# Javascript if else keeps iterating versus returning a single selection and executing it

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

This code should choose one value from the array and then execute according to that value.  Instead, the code selects multiples from the array and then iterates through the else if multiple times.

Here is the first case of the switch with the issues:

```js
switch (autoshuffle) {
    case "random":
        autoshuffle = ["true", "false", "ascending", "descending"][
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
        ];
        console.log(autoshuffle);
        if (autoshuffle == "true") {
            shufflexup(file_list);
            console.log("sort shuffled");
        } else if (autoshuffle == "ascending") {
            file_list.sort();
            console.log("sort ascending");
        } else if (autoshuffle == "descending") {
            file_list.sort();
            file_list.reverse();
            console.log("sort descending");
        }
        break;
}
```

Here are some console results:

**Run 1**

```
true  
false  
ascending  
sort ascending
```

**Run 2**

```
ascending  
sort ascending  
descending  
sort descending  
descending  
sort descending
```

Due to this multiple unwanted sorts are occurring and impacting performance.

I tried adding an ending else, but it made no difference.

Certain I'm doing something stupid.  Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Why are you using an if/else inside a switch statement?

Comment: Your array values are all strings but you compare to true (a bool). Is this intended?

Comment: There's nothing here that suggests that your code automatically runs for each branch, in fact I don't think it's possible based on what you shared. I suspect that the issue is *outside* this function. Somethings calls this function multiple times.

Comment: Thank you Evert.  That is exactly what is occurring.  My perspective was too narrow.